# Ease Out and In Read More Text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the text with 'read more', when read more is clicked the text expands. Right now the text expands instantly, I want to make expand (ease out) more slowly.

HTML

```
<div class="comment more">
As the founder of lol and lol of the deisng lol and design principal, Ken works closely with designers and project managers throughout the project. In t t t this leadership role, he supervises client. As the founder of lol and lol of the deisng lol and design principal, Ken works closely with designers and project managers throughout the project. In t this leadership role, he supervises client. As the founder of lol and lol of the deisng lol and design principal, Ken works closely with designers and project managers throughout the project. In t this leadership role, he supervises client.As the founder of lol and lol of the deisng lol and design principal, Ken works closely with designers and project managers throughout the project. In t this leadership role, he supervises client.
</div>
```

CSS

```
.comment {
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.12em;
    max-width: 800px;
}
a.morelink{text-decoration:none;outline:none}.morecontent span{display:none}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 200;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Read More";
    var lesstext = "Close";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
        if (content.length > showChar) {
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar - 1, content.length - showChar);
            var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">' + ellipsestext + '</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
            $(this).html(html);
        }
    });
    $(".morelink").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/039zkqbL/1/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.toggle()`, try

```
.animate({height: "auto"}, slow);
```

You can also change the speed to fast, or to be more specific you can use milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Change lines

```
$(this).parent().prev().toggle();
$(this).prev().toggle();
```

to

```
$(this).parent().prev().slideToggle(); //or slideToggle("slow");
$(this).prev().slideToggle();
```

I tried it but you will have to make some tuning about character counts. Some text is repeating at emerging point.

Change

```
var h = content.substr(showChar - 1, content.length - showChar);
```

to

```
var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
```

Comment: Yes, Thank You, but still i didn't achieve what i was expecting

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe make use of `animate()` and use `max-height` because you can't animate to `height:auto`. Check this:

```
$(".morelink").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
            $(this).parents('.comment').animate({'max-height':'70px'}, 1000);           
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
            $(this).parents('.comment').animate({'max-height':'220px'}, 1000);
        }

        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().fadeToggle(1100);
        return false;
});
```

#### [FiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/039zkqbL/5/)

Answer (score 1):

i wouldn't do it with jquery i would recommend css3 and transitions.

if you want to do it this way you just have to change the height of the second textblock. from 0 to the height is actually has.

if you don't want to calculate the height of the second textblock, you also can set

```
height: auto;
```

and

```
max-height: 0;
```

so you can open it just set the max height to any value height enough and the div will automaticaly stop if the contentheight is reached...

to get exactly what i mean see the updated working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/039zkqbL/8/).

greetings timotheus